# How to make a game object teleport to where a player has clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to make a game object teleport to where a player has clicked on the screen. How may I do this?

Comment: What did you try.  What would you expect to do

Comment: I have not tried anything because I am quite new to unity and c#. But I would expect some code which can find where the player has clicked on the screen and send the game object to that location. This is a 2d game by the way.

Comment: @pokefalle Look at ray casting and finding an intersection point this way.

Comment: I don't understand how I will be able to find when and where the player has clicked with ray-casts because aren't they for detecting collisions with game objects.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it should be a 4 step process:

1. Detect the click
2. Capture mouse position
3. Translate the mouse position to world space
4. Move the game object

#### 1.

For detecting the click, you can check [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) during an `Update()` call.

#### 2.

For capturing the position you can check [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) at the same time you detected the click.

#### 3.

For converting the mousePosition to world space you can use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

#### 4.

Moving the gameObject should be as simple as setting the gameObject's `position` to be the same as the `Vector3` you got from the mousePosition.